Select entire column text when editing
Below tabulator (version 6.3.0) column assignment code works. It is input editor. When user click it, cursor will alway on end of existing text. I would like to highlight entire existing text, when user click it. It means when I enter first character, it will replace entire existing text by entered character.
          { title: "Discount",field: "Discount",
            editor: "input",
            validator: ["numeric"],
          },


You can add selectContents: true option to editorParams of the editable column to select its text content when loaded.  Here is an example:


const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { 
      title: 'Name',
      field: 'name',
      editor: 'input',
      editorParams: {
        selectContents: true
      }
    },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age'},
    { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender'},
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    { title: 'Color', field: 'col' }
  ]
})
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.3.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>



Reference: https://tabulator.info/docs/6.3/edit#editor-input
